# how can I extract a PDF stored in my app resources.raw directory to the working device

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a pdf Form stored in my xamarin android  app resources.
I want that the app user can extract the Form from the resources and fill it.

I found some  samples in nativ android, but I cannot adapt it to Xamarin.
I need to get the resource file to an input stream, but do not succeed.

Comment: is there a reason you can't include it as an Android Asset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you have a file in raw folder of the Resource folder of Android project, you could open a data stream for reading a raw resource.

I add a file named file1 in raw older for reference.

```
 var stream = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.file1);
```

If you want to read the string from the stream, you could use the code below.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        string line=reader.ReadLine();
```

And then, if you want to get this in Xamarin.Forms, you could use `DependencyService`. For more details, check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction